# simplest way to add a type to a map in clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm searching for the lightest way to add a type to a clojure map
I know i could use records for doing that but i'm wondering if i can do it with regular maps

i've got a function to create a map that represent a person:

```
(defn person [first-name last-name] {:first-name first-name :last-name last-name})
```

i would like to be able to do something like that:

```
(def wayne (person "Wayne" "Shorter"))
....
(type wayne) 
=> person
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could attach some [metadata](http://clojure.org/metadata):

```
(defn person [first-name last-name]
      (with-meta {:first-name first-name :last-name last-name}
                 {:type 'Person}))

(def wayne (person "Wayne" "Shorter"))

(type wayne) ;; Person
```

Comment: If OP really just wants a way to _tag_ certain values this here is the idiomatic solution IMHO. Well done! :)